# Parser Error in page definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Parser Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Compiler executable file
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe cannot be found.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ page title="" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Mandi.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_wmcxwbn2" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
```

> Source File: /Default.aspx    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Comment: You cannot inherit multiple classes (pages).

Comment: Exactly, what makes you think you could just add a comma here?  inherits="_Default, App_Web_wmcxwbn2"